# 301 redirect rails herokuapp to another domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, heroku

I have an old rails site hosted on heroku `example.herokuapp.com`that I'd like to 301 redirect all traffic to a new site that is hosted elsewhere. I've looked around heroku's documentation and all the use cases are for adding a custom domain to a herokuapp or redirecting within the app from http to https. I'm not using heroku anymore, but I still have some SEO traffic coming to that site so there is a need to send that to my new site.

I could add a 301 redirect to my rails config file. Is this the best way or is there a better solution? I was hoping there was a setting in heroku that I could change so it wouldn't rely on my hobby server to start up, recognize the request and then redirect it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User `rack-rewrite` gem. As far as I know it can't be set on heroku.

production.rb

```
config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Runtime, Rack::Rewrite) do
  r301 %r{.*}, "https://example.com$&", 
  :if => Proc.new { |rack_env| rack_env['SERVER_NAME'] != 'example.com' }
end
```